# How the model class will be design to fetch the nested array object in recycler view?

Tags: json, android-studio, model, retrofit

> I am using a free IMDB api for Json practicing , but don't know how to fetch these data through recycler view.
> Here is the Json api data which I need to fetch.

```
{
    "technical_specs": [
        [
            "Runtime",
            "2 hr 28 min (148 min)"
        ],
        [
            "Sound Mix",
            "Dolby Digital | DTS | SDDS"
        ],
        [
            "Color",
            "Color"
        ],
        [
            "Aspect Ratio",
            "2.39 : 1"
        ],
        [
            "Camera",
            "Arriflex 235, "
        ],
        [
            "Laboratory",
            "Imagica Corporation, Shinagawa-ku, "
        ],
        [
            "Film Length",
            "3,925 m (Portugal) <br> 4,037 m (Sweden)"
        ],
        [
            "Negative Format",
            "35 mm (also horizontal) (Kodak Vision3 250D 5207, Vision3 500T 5219) <br> 65 mm (Kodak Vision3 250D 5207, Vision3 500T 5219)"
        ],
        [
            "Cinematographic Process",
            "Panavision (anamorphic) <br> Panavision Super 70 (some scenes) <br> VistaVision (aerial shots)"
        ],
        [
            "Printed Film Format",
            "35 mm (Kodak Vision 2383) <br> 70 mm (horizontal) (IMAX DMR blow-up) (Kodak Vision 2383) <br> D-Cinema"
        ]
    ]

}
```

> > I got confused to make a proper model for nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this JSON response , assuming the "technical_specs" as not fixed key, if you are using Retrofit to fetch the data, the method will be as follows,

```
fun fetchData(): Response<HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>>
```

and then you can use this hashmap to populate your recycler view, you dont need to create any Pojo class for this.